# ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor has incompitable types

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer and I'm getting this error

`ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be applied to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close)
```

`R.drawable.ic.drawer` is giving error. I searched in entire `stackoverflow` and found another topic that says, you need to create a toolbar and add it as action bar and pass this toolbar to this constructor, but how do I create a toolbar so that `ic_drawer` can be displayed.

I tried this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = new ToolBar(getApplicationContext);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
```

but when I run, the app crashes. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarDrawerToggle Constructor is as follow.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity,
            DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
            Toolbar toolbar, 
            int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
            int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

You are passing `R.drawable.ic_drawer` drawable instead of toolbar that's why you are getting this error.

Add toolbar in your layout file as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout
            ...>

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
              android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
              ...>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Pass your toolbar as the third parameter.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close)
```

Hope it solves your error.

Comment: app crashes when I pass toolbar as the third parameter

Comment: What is the crash log? @HeisenBerg

Comment: @HeisenBerg Have you added toolbar in your layout file?Check my updated answer.

Comment: I've found a solution for now by changing from v7 to v4. I'll definitely try this later. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's crazy that the [training material from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) uses a deprecated method (v4) with a constructor requiring a drawable.

The up-to-date (Sept 2015) version of ActionBarDrawerToggle uses a constructor with a toolbar instead. However, if you are simply using the Action Bar to toggle the navigation drawer, use [this simpler constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int)) instead.

> Blockquote
>   The given Activity will be linked to the specified DrawerLayout and its Actionbar's Up button will be set to a custom drawable.
>   This drawable shows a Hamburger icon when drawer is closed and an arrow when drawer is open. It animates between these two states as the drawer opens.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my codes:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    DrawerCloseListener {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_nav);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

/*
 * (non-avadoc) <p>Title: onResume</p> <p>Description: </p>
 * 
 * @params
 * 
 * @overrided @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon_nav);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*
 * (non-avadoc) <p>Title: onConfigurationChanged</p> <p>Description: </p>
 * 
 * @params @param newConfig
 * 
 * @overrided @see
 * android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity#onConfigurationChanged
 * (android.content.res.Configuration)
 */
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/*
 * (non-avadoc) <p>Title: onPostCreate</p> <p>Description: </p>
 * 
 * @params @param savedInstanceState
 * 
 * @overrided @see android.app.Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

/*
 * (non-avadoc) <p>Title: onBackPressed</p> <p>Description: </p>
 * 
 * @params
 * 
 * @overrided @see android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity#onBackPressed()
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

/*
 * (non-avadoc) <p>Title: onDrawerClose</p> <p>Description: </p>
 * 
 * @params
 * 
 * @overrided @see com.yeepay.stall.abs.DrawerCloseListener#onDrawerClose()
 */
@Override
public void onDrawerClose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
    }
}
```

}

And here is my layout:

```
<!-- I use android:fitsSystemWindows because I am changing the color of the statusbar as well -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<!-- Main layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/activity_home_toolbar_layout" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:name="com.yeepay.stall.frag.HomeContentFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Nav drawer -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:name="com.yeepay.stall.frag.HomeDrawerFrag"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_home_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And at last, my `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg_layer_dark"
android:gravity="center"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/color_toolbar_text" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

[ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) v4 is now deprecated. You should use  [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) in support-v7-appcompat.

You don't need anymore to specify the resources of the image:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

    }
};

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

For the complete example see http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/Android-Lollipop-Navigation-Drawer-Example-Using-Appcompat-21.html

Comment: Actually i was using v7. I changed it to v4 and its working now. Thanks

Comment: You should use V7, just change your V4 constructor to V7